# Jquery help: Show/Hide "add to cart" div based on multiple dropdown selections

Tags: jquery, dropdown, show-hide

I have a product with multiple dropdown options and a unique "add to cart" div for each possible combination. I'd like to show the correct "add to cart" div based on a selection made between two pulldown menus.

Here's the sample html...and a poor start at some of show/hide jquery.  I'm a total noob. Thanks in advance.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SELECTWOOD').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == 'MAPLE')
      {
        $("#W8").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#W8").hide();
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<body>

<select id='SELECTWOOD'>
<option value="WALNUT">SOLID WALNUT</option>
<option value="MAPLE">SOLID MAPLE</option>
</select>

<select id='SELECTSIZE'>
<option value="2">2 SEATER (30")</option>
<option value="4">4-6 SEATER (60")</option>
<option value="6">6 SEATER (76")</option>
<option value="8">8 SEATER (84")</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='W2'>ADD TO CART1<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='W46'>ADD TO CART2<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='W6'>ADD TO CART3<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='W8'>ADD TO CART4<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='M2'>ADD TO CART5<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='M46'>ADD TO CART6<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='M6'>ADD TO CART7<br/>
<div style='display:none;' id='M8'>ADD TO CART8<br/>
<br/>
    <input type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
    <br/>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: FYI the <input> tag was an error - that line should not be there

Answer (score 0):

Close div tag by adding to each div `</div>`

```
<div style='display:none;' id='W2'>ADD TO CART1</div><br/>
....
```

and add `style='display:none;'` to input

```
<input style='display:none;' type='text' class='text' name='business' value size='20' />
```

at last hide or show the input with the correspondent div based on a selection

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#SELECTWOOD').on('change', function() {

          if ( this.value == 'MAPLE'){ 
            console.log('show')
            $("#W8").show();
            $("input").show();
          }
          else{ 
            $("#W8").hide();
            $("input").hide();
          }
        });
    });
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks for the reply! what would be the script to select one div if both SELECTWOOD and SELECTSIZE were in play? In my current code i only have SELECTWOOD. Don't know how to add SELECTSIZE to the operation